# Ubuntu 22.04 wifi doesn't connect to any network with activation of connecting failed

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, lenovo

My wifi doesn't connect to any network names, after a day previously it worked fine. My device is Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15ABA7. My wifi modem is Real Tek Semiconductor
`Kernel Linux image 6.5.0-25 generic Lspci -nnk -d ::0280 Real Tek Semiconductor 10ec:b852 Kernel driver in use rtw89_8852be Kernel modules rtw89_8852be, rtw_8852be`

I have many kernel modules installed do not know which one to blacklist: rtw89 core, rtw89pci, rtw_8852b

I read and unfortunately applied many of articles, blog's suggestions. I even tried to use from UEFI olsa kernel 6.5.0-21 there I had no appearance of wifi . I blacklisted driver in modprobe.d file then deleted some drivers which were related to mine, after sudo gedir I wrote back some of them. I tried reinstalling of Linux headers, then rtw89 driver, inetc/netplan I removed to TMP file 01-network-manage-all.yaml file then tried to bring back from TMP folder, couldn't find, then rewrited by myself. Tried suspend module for hibernation to change back from 3 to 1.
Messed up in one word.
So, now I want to ask the same question by myself if anyone could help me to get on the right path to resolve my wifi issue in Lenovo IdeaPad 3 for Ubuntu 22.04.
Thanks for your reading